# How to check whether the shift key is being held in C#?

Tags: c#, virtual, keycode, uppercase, lowercase

I was writing a method which should handle lower/uppercase letters by receiving virtualcodes (as you know the virtualcode always returns a code and can not render uppercase or lowercase letters by itself). If anyone is interested, I found a solution by using the `Control.IsKeyLocked` and `Control.ModifierKeys` classes:

```
bool isCapsLockOn = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
bool isShiftOn = Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift;
```

The first solution I was trying to implement was to handle the shift key using Control.IsKeyLocked(), not long after I found out that IsKeyLocked should be used ONLY for keys which can be actually locked like numlock, capslock, etc. The following code DID NOT WORK:

```
bool isLShiftOn = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.LShiftKey);
bool isRShiftOn = Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.RShiftKey);
```

Okay I actually found the solution to my problem by handling whether the caps lock is on/off and whether the shift is actually pressed using Control.IsKeyLocked and Control.ModifierKeys combined with an if statement (to handle lowercase when caps lock is on/shift is pressed and upper case when caps lock is off/shift is pressed, etc and vice-versa). I am now curious why the above code DID NOT WORK and actually even the code below it did not execute. Why the compiler didn't throw an error?. I suppose that this throws the application somehow in a "waiting" state waiting for the shift key to be locked down which can not happen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/515118/182344
Check this answer

Comment: @RredCat: Please read the whole post. I'm not actually looking for a solution but for an explanation to why the first thing I tried didn't work and what actually happens "behind the scene".

Comment: IMO your whole approach is flawed. There is no trivial relationship between keys and characters. How do you plan on handling different keyboard layouts (including dead keys, shift-for-digits on french keyboards, Alt+Gr combinations) or even worse IMEs?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have no idea. I was looking at the toAscii and toUnicode functions of the windows API but could not find a decent example and explanation on how to use them. This is why I came up with this which seems to work at least on the English layout.

Comment: A good approach is handling `WM_CHAR` instead of working on raw keys.

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you provide a short example? Where is WM_CHAR returned?

Comment: The [`KeyPress` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) gives you a character directly.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I'm actually looking for a low-level solution. The way I'm getting the character code is by using Marshal.ReadInt32() in a low-level hook callback, I don't see a way to implement a KeyPress event into this

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)